# Teamcity and WDK 7.1

Tags: teamcity, wdk

I'm trying to configure automatic building of project whick use WDK 7.1 on my TeamCity server.

Manually I need to start "x86 Free Build Environment" (part of WDK) to set my local environment and basically it calls this script: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\setenv.bat C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\ fre x86 WIN7

Then I need to proceed to folder with project and "build" in opened command prompt (with correct environment).

But when I'm trying to do it in TeamCity build step it set environment variables for TeamCity step and works incorrectly (doesn't proceed to folder with project and tries to build WDK base folder).

I tried to write bat file with:

```
call C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\setenv.bat C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\ fre x86 WIN7
cd path_to_project
build
```

And start it from TeamCity but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `setenv.bat` sets variables for the account that runs your TeamCity services?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using Python script and subprocess module